# Define structure of received object?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, code-completion

Is there any way, either in the JavaScript specs or the IntelliJ platform, to define the structure of an object you receive from, say, an AJAX call?

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://myapi.domain.com/apitest',
    success: function(payload) {
       let username = payload.userNameField; //unresolved variable "userNameField"
    }
});
```

In the above example, WebStorm reports that `payload.userNameField` is an "unresolved variable".

Is there any way I can define the object so that it doesn't show errors and maybe autocompletes as well?

Comment: Is `payload.userNameField` defined?

Comment: On the backend (API) it is...  It's not in the client code, which is what I'm asking.  Can I simply define `payload = { userNameField: "" }` outside the ajax call?

Comment: `payload = { userNameField: "" }` would be a different variable than `payload` at `success` function of `$.ajax()`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That's what I thought, but you casually asked if it was defined like I was missing something obvious... What I'm trying to achieve is outlined clearly in my question.

Comment: Still not certain what expected result is?

Comment: The expected result is to be able to reference `payload.userNameField` without Webstorm telling me it's undefined.

Comment: Have not tried Webstorm or IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Please read tags and full post before commenting. :(

Comment: Did read the tags. If `.userNameField` is undefined at object at `$.ajax()` `success` an error should still be thrown whether using Webstorm and IntelliJ IDEA or not

Comment: Have you tried defining a [custom complex type with jsdocs](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html)? You could then document the function given to `success` and define the payload with the new type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @chazsolo for pointing me to JSDoc's "[Custom complex type](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html)" which is natively supported by Webstorm, this solution works great:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://myapi.domain.com/apitest',
    success: processResponse
});

/**
 * Definition of the object returned by the api call
 * @typedef {Object} processResponse~payload
 * @property {string} userNameField - Username returned by API
 */
/**
 * Definition of function that handles the response
 * @class
 * @param {...processResponse~payload} payload - the data returned by the call
 */

function processResponse(payload) {
       let username = payload.userNameField; //no errors now and autocomplete works!
};
```